# "Running a 64-bit JVM is not supported on this platform" with java -d64 option on 64bit linux

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

I have a 64 bit linux os:

```
$ uname -p
x86_64
```

java -version listed:

```
java version "1.6.0_43"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)
```

I am trying to run a 64 bit jvm with 4096 min heap size ( Its a heavy weight app ). When i add -d64 option i get the message

```
Running a 64-bit JVM is not supported on this platform
```

With out `-d4` option and with heap size 2048 it works fine. But the memory isnt enough so i need to use 64 bit JVM with 4Gigs. Can anyone tell me why its not accepting `d64` ?

Comment: Maybe you only have a 32 bit jvm installed ? You'll need a 64 bit jvm to run in 64 bit mode.

Comment: First, be sure about that u are using the right java version for your process. Second, be sure that the parameter is passed into the process correctly(define it before the memory args).

Comment: @Adi Dembark : How do you say it is a 64 version? The -version doesnt give any 64 bit info and when i googled it , it said there are both 32 and 64 bit versions certified

Comment: @Neron - The version listed above is the one i am using for the process and yes i use the -d64 option before setting heap size.

Comment: @maveric Your installation is a 32 bit jvm, so uninstall it, and install a 64 bit jvm. Unfortunately the java -version doesn't show you if it's a 32 oe 64 bit installation in all cases.

Comment: @nos - can you tell me how i can check if i am running a 32 bit jvm ?

Comment: A 64-bit jvm should include the string  "64-bit server" in its version output. A 32-bit jvm will not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Adi Dembark and @nos found the issue. It was indeed a 32 bit jvm. changing to 64 bit fixed it.